# How do you load weights into CudnnLSTM in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to get CudnnLSTM to work with CoVE (https://github.com/salesforce/cove) but I could not find any place to load pretrained weights into the CudnnLSTM model.

Would appreciate if anyone with experience in pre-initializing a CudnnLSTM cell could let me know how to achieve this.

Thanks!

Comment: I have been wondering this myself, and I don't know the answer, but might the `CudnnLSTMSaveable` class have something to do with it? https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/cudnn_rnn/CudnnLSTMSaveable The documentation for this class is not very helpful.

Comment: You can supply kernel and bias initializers to CudnnLSTM's [constructor](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/cudnn_rnn/CudnnLSTM#__init__). Will that suffice?